# Javascript error when using CKEditor in JSF page

Tags: jsf-2, ckeditor, primefaces-extensions

I tried to use the CKEditor in a JSF page like:

```
<pe:ckEditor id="editor" value="#{messagingController.messageContent}" width="600"/>
```

The editor will appear in Internet Explorer but not in Fire Fox or Chrome

FireBug shows me the following error:

```
SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified
```

And Chrome console shows me the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to set the 'innerHTML' property on 'Element': 
The provided markup is invalid XML, and therefore cannot be inserted into an XML document.

CKEDITOR.plugins.add.afterInit
(anonymous function)
k
CKEDITOR.scriptLoader.load
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
k
CKEDITOR.scriptLoader.load
CKEDITOR.resourceManager.load
i
(anonymous function)
k
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
k
l
o
(anonymous function)
```

Is this a bug or something? Can I include this component any other way around?

I also use the latest primefaces extentions lib:

```
<groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
<artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0</version>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the mime type of my page!when I changed it from `application/xhtml+xml` to `text/html`, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Small addition to the already correct answer:

Also in iOS Safari this Syntax Error can appear. An indication is your document variable `compatMode:"CSS1Compat"` (in js), then ckEditor will cause an error at this function `x.innerHTML = "some string with html entities"` because the document is read with the wrong mime type.

ckEditor works fine for me when the document has `compatMode:"BackCompat"`. This is set by the browser and depends on the content-type resp. media-type.